# Invalid character '\' in mnemonic

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, shellcode

I'm asm/shellcode newbie and I have trouble with compile example shellcode included as template in ParrotOS.

I looked through following topics, but It couldn't solve my problem:

[Assembly error: invalid character '$' in mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257715/assembly-error-invalid-character-in-mnemonic)

[Invalid character (0xe2) in mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283126/invalid-character-0xe2-in-mnemonic)

I tried use `as` command instead of `gcc`, however I got this same error.

```
char code[] = 

    "\xe9\x1e\x00\x00\x00"  //          jmp    8048083 <MESSAGE>
    "\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00"  //          mov    $0x4,%eax
    "\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00"  //          mov    $0x1,%ebx
    "\x59"                  //          pop    %ecx
    "\xba\x0f\x00\x00\x00"  //          mov    $0xf,%edx
    "\xcd\x80"              //          int    $0x80
    "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00"  //          mov    $0x1,%eax
    "\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00"  //          mov    $0x0,%ebx
    "\xcd\x80"              //          int    $0x80
    "\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff"  //          call   8048065 <GOBACK>
    "give me a bottle of rum!\r\n";     // OR       "\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x20\x57"
                            //          "\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x0d\x0a"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (*(void(*)())code)();

    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc shellcode.s

shellcode.s: Assembler messages:
shellcode.s:1: Error: no such instruction: `char code[]='
shellcode.s:3: Error: invalid character '\' in mnemonic
shellcode.s:4: Error: invalid character '\' in mnemonic
shellcode.s:5: Error: invalid character '\' in mnemonic
shellcode.s:6: Error: invalid character '\' in mnemonic
shellcode.s:7: Error: invalid character '\' in mnemonic
shellcode.s:8: Error: invalid character '\' in mnemonic
shellcode.s:9: Error: invalid character '\' in mnemonic
shellcode.s:10: Error: invalid character '\' in mnemonic
shellcode.s:11: Error: invalid character '\' in mnemonic
shellcode.s:12: Error: invalid character '\' in mnemonic
shellcode.s:13: Error: no such instruction: `give me a bottle of rum!\r\n"'
shellcode.s:17: Error: junk `(int argc,char **argv)' after expression
shellcode.s:17: Error: operand size mismatch for `int'
shellcode.s:18: Error: no such instruction: `{'
shellcode.s:19: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `('
shellcode.s:21: Error: no such instruction: `return 0'
shellcode.s:22: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `}'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is C code, but it has a `.s` extension which indicates assembly. Rename your file to `shellcode.c`.

Comment: Thank you, that was a little tricky to debug. I didn't expect that gcc recognize extensions, because I never felt that during programming in C/C++. I'm having segmentation fault currently, but I'll try solve that myself.

Answer (score 6):

By default, gcc decides which language to compile the file in according to its extension.

Renaming the file properly according to its contents is the right thing to do ([as already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394415/6451573))

If for some reason you can't rename the file, you can also force `gcc` to compile a file with any extension in a given (supported) language using `-x` option:

```
gcc -x c shellcode.s
```

This switch sets the language but doesn't set the default link options. Trying `gcc` on a C++ file to create an executable fails because `gcc` link driver doesn't add the C++ libraries by default.

Comment: "*By default, gcc decides which language to compile the file in according to its extension.*" - Does that mean someone could compile a .cpp file with `gcc` instead of `g++`, like `gcc -o foo bar.cpp` without a problem?

Comment: actually it would compile but the link will fail unless you explicitly add the C++ libs (or use g++ to link)

Comment: Right, but I could use `gcc` to compile and `g++` to link?

Comment: `gcc -c foo.cpp` then `g++ -o foo foo.o`